# Git: Merge local master into my own test branch

Tags: git

I have my local test branch and changes were updated to `master`

So, I want my test branch to get new material from master branch

I do not want to merge my thing into Master. only merge master into my branch.

what I did:

```
$ git checkout test

$ git merge master
```

then it said

```
Already up to date.
```

However, I see no change in my test local branch.. I know boss make some update in master, if really merge successfully, my local test branch should have the new file but nothing happens

Comment: strongly recommend to read about GIT before touching. In best case you'll ask question here. In worst case.. you don't want to know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do:

```
git merge master
```

you take your **local** master.
You should get the updated data first from remote repo.
So either do:

```
git checkout your_branch

# get data from remote 'origin' repo 'master' branch and merge into checked out branch
git pull origin master
```

or:

```
git checkout master
git pull # takes remote master changes to local one.

git checkout your_branch
git merge master # merge local (already updated) branch to checked out one
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option which requires minimal changes from your current approach:

```
git checkout test
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

The reason your merge does not seem to do anything is that you are likely using an outdated local version.  You really want to merge in the latest version on the remote.  This is represented locally by `origin/master`, and you can update this tracking branch by just doing a `git fetch`.  Note that my proposed solution does not even require switching from `test` to `master`.